# How to truncate dynamodb DB table via cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, truncate

DynamoDB tables can be truncated via AWS console, but I'd like to do this in a script.
All the answers I saw on S.O. regarding this topic involved 'scans' and similar stuff that I didn't completely understand.  I'm wondering if there is a simple directive that I can use to accomplish this truncation.  Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean `delete-table`? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/delete-table.html)

Comment: TRUNCATE is the RDBMS term for deleting all items, as opposed to DROP which is the RDBMS term for deleting the table. If the AWS DynamoDB Console supports truncation then it is simply scanning and (batch) deleting items.

Comment: Posted an answer, which is simple directive to use. Let me know if it works for your use case :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra - thanks for your answer.  i will give it a try when i get some spare cycles.

Answer (score 5):

Use dynamodbdump

It has a wipe-data option which is fast and simple and less hassle, you dont have to write any script or any manual effort rather just running this simple command .

example

```
dynamodump wipe-data --throughput 5 --table your-table --region eu-west-1
```

https://github.com/mifi/dynamodump

Comment: Better to clarify that the tool has a `dynamodump wipe-data` operation.

Comment: Thanks, Jatin.. i did try it.. unfortunately didn't quite work for me. Maybe my dumb error.. i worked around another way. But appreciate your answering !

Comment: what was the error you faced, I have used this tool, and it had worked for me, so please let me know what did you tried, and what was the results so that I can help further

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. You need to delete the table. What all the scripts are doing is scanning the entire table and delete each item. Better to delete the table and create it with the same name

Comment: Thats exactly what I wrote. Scripts providing to truncate a dynamodb table scan and delete each item (or as batch)...But it makes no sense to do it because it involves scanning an entire table which could by costly

Answer (score 0):

While it's not straight forward, you can combine a couple commands to get you there w/o needing 3rd party tools.  What we're doing here is scanning the table 25 records at a time (the max we can batch execute), using some jmespath shenanigans in the --query to format it into batch execute statements, then passing that to the batch-execute-statement command.  Lather, rinse, repeat until the size of bulk.json is 3 bytes or in other words "[]" an empty list.

Adjust as needed for your table name, sort key, range key (if any), and of course data types (they're "S" string in this example).

This works...needs no extra tools...but it's hardly efficient.  If you want to get fancy, recoding it in python using a worker thread pool to pass the batches off to would likely gain it 100x speed.

```
> bulk.json # so our first pass doesn't break the while test
while [ $(du -b bulk.json | cut -f 1) -ne 3 ]; do
    aws dynamodb scan \
        --max-items 25 \
        --table     my_table \
        --query "Items[].{\"Statement\" : join('', ['DELETE FROM \"my_table\" WHERE \"MySortKey\" = \'',MySortKey.S,'\' AND \"MyRangeKey\" = \'', MyRangeKey.S, '\''])}" \
        --output json \
        > bulk.json
    aws dynamodb batch-execute-statement \
        --statements file://bulk.json \
        --query "join('', ['Deleted ', to_string(length(Responses)), ' records.'])"; \
        --output text
done
```